# How many BNF-like grammar specifications does Python have?

Tags: python, grammar, abstract-syntax-tree, bnf, code-documentation

There are at least 3 grammar-like specifications within the Python 3.9.1 reference documents 'library-3.9.1.pdf' and 'reference-3.9.1.pdf' (aka https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html and https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/grammar.html).

There is the "abstract grammar" [library-3.9.1.pdf, page 1895](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/ast.html) that looks like this:

```
-- ASDL's 4 builtin types are:
-- identifier, int, string, constant

module Python
{
    mod = Module(stmt* body, type_ignore* type_ignores)
        | Interactive(stmt* body)
        | Expression(expr body)
        | FunctionType(expr* argtypes, expr returns)

    stmt = FunctionDef(identifier name, arguments args,
                       stmt* body, expr* decorator_list, expr? returns,
                       string? type_comment)
          | AsyncFunctionDef(identifier name, arguments args,
                             stmt* body, expr* decorator_list, expr? returns,
                             string? type_comment)
...
```

There is the "PEG grammar for Python"/"full grammar specification" ("a mixture of EBNF and PEG") ([reference-3.9.1.pdf, Chapter 10, pages 111-120](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/grammar.html) that looks like this:

```
# type_expressions allow */** but ignore them
type_expressions:
    | ','.expression+ ',' '*' expression ',' '**' expression 
    | ','.expression+ ',' '*' expression 
    | ','.expression+ ',' '**' expression 
    | '*' expression ',' '**' expression 
    | '*' expression 
    | '**' expression 
    | ','.expression+ 

statements: statement+ 
statement: compound_stmt  | simple_stmts
...
```

And there are various snippets of "BNF notation" that are "used to describe syntax, not lexical analysis" sprinkled about [eg., reference-3.9.1.pdf, pages 65-108](https://docs.python.org/3.9/reference/expressions.html) that look like this:

```
comprehension ::=  assignment_expression comp_for
comp_for      ::=  ["async"] "for" target_list "in" or_test [comp_iter]
comp_iter     ::=  comp_for | comp_if
comp_if       ::=  "if" or_test [comp_iter]
```

This last bit of "BNF notation" seems the most useful for my purposes, and looks very similar to the "full grammar specification", but it defines all sorts of syntactic types (like e.g.  "assignment_expression" and "comp_iter" (reference-3.9.1.pdf, page 67)) which aren't mentioned in either the "full grammar specification" or the "abstract grammar".

**What is the relationship between all of these, and, more importantly, is the "BNF notation" that is "used to describe syntax" an actual specification of some sort, or just being used for exposition within the reference document? And, if it is an actual specification, where might it be found, i.e. as a single file that can be conveniently parsed?**

Regards!

Comment: Are you asking whether BNF itself is specified somewhere? It goes back to the ALGOL-60 days, but modern practice has somewhat evolved since then. The IETF uses something they call EBNF which I believe originated with the SMTP spec in RFC821 / RFC822. It does not directly translate to computer code AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks @tripleee : no, I'm asking whether the BNF-like specs that are sprinkled throughout  reference-3.9.1.pdf, pages 65-108 are, in fact, formal specs, or whether they are just expository, and if they are in fact formal, then where I might find them collected together. I am also a bit curious why they reference syntax node-types ("assignment_expression", "comp_iter", and so on) that are found no where else.

Comment: They are just expository and they're not collected together anywhere. Sorry. `assignment_expression` and `comp_iter` are not "node-types". They're just the names of syntactic variables. (In the C declaration `int x, y;`, `int` is a type and `x` and `y` are variable names. If you change `int` to something else, like `double`, you change the semantics of the program. If you change `x` and `y` to `rightwards` and `upwards`, you change nothing except for how the program is read by human readers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar used to build Python isn't on your list at all. You can find it in the source bundle as [Grammar/python.gram](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Grammar/python.gram). Note that it has five different start symbols for different compilation contexts (complete files, interactive input, single expressions, etc.), although most of the grammar is shared. This grammar is actually used by the parser generator to produce the parser actually used by the CPython implementation, so it describes perfectly the inputs accepted by the concrete Python interpreter (of course, subject to change in future versions). As noted in the comments near the top of the file, the syntax of the grammar file itself are defined in a PEP.

But it's not necessarily useful for documentary purposes, and it is not definitive in the sense that it defines the language, in the sense that one might expect from a language standard. Python is not really standardized, so it might be unreasonable to ask for a definitive reference grammar. But the grammar scattered through the Python reference manual is probably as close as you're going to get. Those productions are for expository purposes, though, and they need to be considered along with the accompanying narrative text. (That's generally true of reference grammars, even for standardized grammars, because a context-free grammar cannot capture all the syntactic aspects of any real-life programming language, possibly with a couple of exceptions. So it's usual that the reference grammar for a language will accept a superset of the set of valid programs, and the narrative in the standard provides additional constraints which cannot be expressed in a CFG.)

The collected grammar at the end of the reference manual is supposedly a summary of the snippets, but as I understand it, it's generated mechanically from the `python.gram` file. So it's possible that there are divergences between it and the language described in the manual.

The abstract grammar listed in the `ast` module documentation actually defines the structure of the abstract syntax tree, so it's not a grammar at all in the usual sense (i.e. a description of a linear sequence of symbols) but rather a collection of structure definitions, each one describing the nature of a typed node in the abstract syntax tree. It corresponds directly to the objects you'll find in an AST built with the `ast` module, but it doesn't attempt to  constrain the syntax of a program being parsed. The text in the library reference is the contents of an actual source file, [Parser/Python.asdl](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Parser/Python.asdl), which is mechanically processed into declarations and code used by the CPython parser to produce an AST.

Comment: Thanks very much @rici. This is very helpful. But your answer also raises many new questions. I am a bit surprised to hear that 'Python is not really standardized', and bewildered to see so many BNF-like files and formats and 'grammars' floating about. And it also seems odd that one has to go to CPython to find something approaching a rigorous specification. Indeed if I search 'gram' in my Python installation I'll get a few dozen files that have some form or another of BNF-like descriptions of something or another.

Comment: Also I don't quite understand your statement 'it doesn't attempt to constrain the syntax' viz the ast grammar. Do you mean to say it doesn't operate at a lexical level? I would think that constraining the ordering and plugging of the ast's symbols one into another would also count as constraining syntax, no?

Comment: Also, @rici, may I ask, how does one match versions of the CPython grammar in your first link (Grammar/python.gram) with Python versions? I see no version references there at the Github, but perhaps I just don't know where to look.

Comment: And in the end I am still a bit confused as to why there are so many BNF-like specifications in the first place, each defining slightly different sets of 'nodes' or 'types'. For example the CPython Grammar/python in your link does contain the "assignment_expression" definition, but does not contain "comp_iter". I am guessing that they are targeting different phases of the run process, perhaps one for conversion from code to the AST, and another for compilation to C, and perhaps there are other intermediate forms and phases that could be targeted as well.

Comment: @berniethejet: (1) No standards organization has responsibility for Python, and the CPython implementation is effectively the reference implementation. There is a process for suggesting and accepting modifications to the language (PEPs), but it's much closer to the RFCs used to suggest modifications to Internet protocols than to something like the C++ international standard. That's not a criticism; it's worked quite well in practice. But the end result is that there is no biblical or constitutional document which defines Python.

Comment: @berniethejet: (2) The AST does not define the order of anything, and it doesn't define syntactic inclusion relationships at all. What it defines are a collection of bags of named attributes (which have no formal ordering; otherwise they wouldn't need to be named) and not all of which relate to syntax at all (see the `expr_context` attribute type, for example, or the `is_async` attribute in a `comprehension`). You can think of these bags as analogous to Python objects (indeed, that's what they're used to define). The use of "grammar" to describe the definition needs to be interpreted...

Comment: ... as the section title indicates, abstractly. There is such a thing as a tree grammar, but this isn't really one of those either. It's really much closer to a set of structured type declarations. It does define a set of concrete types which are actually produced by the AST module, but these types hold semantic information, not syntactic information. (Of course, the semantic information is extracted by the parse, so there is a relationship. But it doesn't condition the parse.)

Comment: @berniethejet: (3) I don't think that a SO comment is an appropriate place to explain how version control systems like GIT work. That's well documented; you can read the GIT book. But to give you a hint, what you're looking for are [tags](https://github.com/python/cpython/tags).

Comment: @berniethejet: (4) I know that it's tempting to think that non-terminals in a grammar have some profound significance, but they don't. They're the grammatical equivalent to local variables in a program. If you use a local declaration like `int sum = a + b;`, you're not making some profound statement about the importance of `sum` in a formal description of the algorithm you're implementing. You're just making it more convenient to refer to `a + b`. Someone else could implement exactly the same algo without that local variable, or with a different convenience variable.

Comment: In particular, neither `assignment_expression` nor `comp_iter` have any meaning beyond their didactic convenience or as useful artefacts in a BNF grammar. They do not "[target] different phases of the run process". The only grammar actually used to parse Python is the one I link to in my answer; the summary grammar in section 10 of the Python reference manual is a simplification of the grammar file, designed to be easier for human readers, and the grammar snippets in the rest of the Python reference manual are only for discursive purposes.

Comment: (Of course, the discursive purposes are best served if the language they describe is the same language as is actually parsed by the Python parser, but it's well-known that there are many ways of writing grammars for the same language, just as there are many ways of writing concrete implementations of algorithms.)

Comment: It's possibly also worth noting that the original Python parser was a modified top-down parser, which imposed certain idiosyncratic restrictions on the way the grammar needed to be written, and that the current Python parser is a PEG grammar, which imposes different idiosyncratic restrictions. Much of the discursive material in the reference manual was written based on the top-down grammar, so it might not correspond character-by-character with the current grammar implementation. But that doesn't mean that it describes a different language. It describes the same language in a different way.

Comment: That was way too much for a comment. So I won't add any more.

Comment: Thanks for the followups. The point about Python being a distributed open source project I think helps me understand how it might be that there can be so many 'BNF-like grammar specifications' floating about. There are many fiefdoms (CPython, Numpy, Pandas,...) publishing bits that are of use to themselves, but no centralized authority to establish a single standard. In this environment the user just has to make his way from one walled enclave to the next.